# Rule for capturing types and/or parameterized paths from werkzeug/Flask routing rules

Tags: python, regex, flask, routes, werkzeug

I have a set of Flask routes

```
/<string:name>/<path:id>/
/<name>/<path:id>/ 
/<string:name>/<id>/
```

I want to use a regex to extract **name** and **id**

```
/{name}/{id}/
/{name}/{id}/ 
/{name}/{id}/
```

For all of them (one regex to rule them all), to work for paths having **type:path** like `/<string:name>/` and also those without type like `/<name>/`

But I am trying with:

```
(<(.*?\:)?(.*?)>)
```

which can only match

```
/{name}/{id}/
/{id}/  # <--- Why this is not matching /{name}/{id}/
/{name}/{id}/
```

Any REGEX expert to help?

**Online REGEX**: https://regex101.com/r/iL3jK2/3
**The issue**: https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger/issues/10

Comment: Doesn't [`(<([^<>]*\:)?([^<>]*)>)`](https://regex101.com/r/gZ2rV3/1) work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
(<([^<>]*:)?([^<>]*)>)
```

The [regex demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/gZ2rV3/1). Not sure you really need the outer `(...)` (only if you use it with `re.findall`, but you can remove them and use `re.finditer` and access all match using `match.group(0)`).

**Explanation:**

- `<([^<>]*:)?` - optional Group 2 matching

  - `<` - a literal `<`
  - `[^<>]*` - zero or more characters other than `<` and `>`
  - `:` - a literal `:`
- `([^<>]*)` - Group 3 matching zero or more characters other than `<` and `>`
- `>` closing `>`

Your pattern is rather greedy as `.*?` matches as many characters as necessary to get to the first `:`. Thus, it goes straight to the `id` ignoring `name`. When using the **negated character class** `[^<>]`, we are sure we won't go through the `>` and match the `name` inside the first pair of `<...>`.

Comment: I just removed the redundant escaping on \: (<([^<>]*:)?([^<>]*)>)

Comment: Yes, I kept it in my initial demo, but `:` is not a special character, so it can be unescaped.